# Conditional compilation for move operations

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

How can I check whether my compiler supports rvalue references or not? Is there a standard preprocessor macro, or do different compilers have different macros? Ideally, I would want to write this:

```
#ifdef RVALUE_REFERENCES_SUPPORTED

foobar(foobar&& that)
{
    // ...
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not aware of any standard preprocessor macro, but:

- Visual Studio introduced support in VC2010, whose internal version is 1600, so you can check with `_MSC_VER >= 1600`
- GCC has supported rvalue references since [version 4.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), so you can check for that version along with `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__`
- Clang defines `__has_feature` [macros](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#cxx_rvalue_references) for doing exactly what you need: `__has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references)`

So for most common compilers, it should be fairly easy to cobble something together yourself.

I am also pretty sure that Boost has a macro for this purpose, which you may be able to use if your project includes Boost (otherwise you could look at their implementation)

Comment: I must admit I really love the way Clang chose to advertise its various features and extensions, it's so much clearer than checking with a version number, and much more detailed too.

Answer (score 9):

[Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/config/config.htm) has `BOOST_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES` for that.

Answer (score 5):

The standard method is to check the standard version : If `__cplusplus==199711L` then you don't have (standard) rvalue references. If `__cplusplus==201103L`, you do. Obviously, this doesn't cover non-standard compilers or non-standard extensions to C++98.